# Google ChromeCast Playlist from iOS app + cast multiple urls

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am developing one iOS app. In that, I have list of .mp4 video url which I wans to cast to Chrome Device.

I have already success to cast one video. But in that, everytime, user has to play on one video to cast, and once it is finished, then need to click on 2nd video to cast.

What I want that,
One globla button to cast entire playlist. So when user click on that buttons, then entire playlist should be play to cast device.

Can anyone has any any idea how to achieve this from iOS application?